# Restricting web API access to a resource to the unauthenticated resource creator

Tags: web-api

My question is about the best way for allowing an unauthenticated user who has created a resource to subsequently access and modify that resource they created via web API.

My web API identifies resources using GUIDs. It supports token-based authentication, and access to particular resources can be limited to certain users.

The API also allows unauthenticated users to create and modify certain resources, but unauthenticated users should only be allowed to access and modify resources they have created.

My plan is to have the web API return a token of some kind as part of the resource creation response. This token can then be stored by the client, and sent in a header on subsequent requests relating to that resource.
The token would have an expiry time, and could be renewed/cancelled based on the user's subsequent actions.

My questions are:
 - Is there a better approach to solving the problem?
 - Or, is there any way to improve this approach? E.g. Is there any advantage to using a JWT for the token over just a simple unique identifier?

Comment: The idea could be adequate or terrible depending on the nature of the client. Is it external? What happens if they lose the token and then need to access the resource? How crucial is their access to the resource?. Finally, I wouldn't call this an unauthenticated access. You *are* authenticating them via the token so you do know who they are in some limited way. This means that you should apply all considerations that you would for an authentication process here.

Comment: @Rad80 The client is a public web site. The resource is a quote a user can obtain and refine as they add more information. The use case is based around a single visit to the site to create and refine a quote and make an order. The restriction is meant to ensure that only the original user can work with that quote. If the user abandons the quote for a period of time etc. they have to start again, so losing the token is not a problem. But maybe there is a simpler or more standard approach I should be using?